# Coloring 3 by 3 square such that every unit square has an even number of squares it shares a vertex with of the same color (including itself).

Tags: combinatorics

Coloring 3 by 3 square such that every unit square has an even number of squares it shares a vertex with of the same color (including itself).

I don't think this is possible, I have done a fair bit of case bashing to this effect but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to approach it?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the graph where each square is a point and two vertices are adjacent if and only if their respective squares share a vertex and they have the same color. You want to create a graph where each point has an odd degree (since you want the degree plus 1 to be odd).

But then the sum of the degrees of the graph would be odd since there is an odd number of points. This is impossible since the sum of the degrees is always even (because it is twice the number of edges).

Comment: $+10^{10}$ That is great. Thanks. Will accept when I can (and applies to all rectangles with an odd number of squares!).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I can't find a construction for 4 by 3. Do you have any thoughts on it. Thanks so much.

Comment: \begin{array}{ccccc} X&X&X\\X&X&X\\O&O&O\\O&O&O\end{array}