# Coloring 4 by 3 square such that every unit square has an even number of squares it shares a vertex with of the same color (including itself).

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Coloring 4 by 3 square such that every unit square has an even number of squares it shares a vertex with of the same color (including itself).

I don't think this is possible, I have done a fair bit of case bashing to this effect but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to approach it?
Thanks so much.

Note seems closely related to the [3 by 3 case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030288/coloring-3-by-3-square-such-that-every-unit-square-has-an-even-number-of-squares/) but the same nice solution doesn't work. 
Is there a construction. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding the problem properly, but what if you coloured the squares with colours 1 and 2 like so?
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 2 & 2\\
2 & 2 & 2
\end{array}$$

Comment: oh. So obvious. I feel a little stupid. That seems right Thanks so much!